# TypeScript with Redux connect pass extra props

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

How to properly pass extra props?

```
const SideBar = connect(
  (state: State) => ({current: state.projects.current}),
  null
)(({className, current}) => (
  <nav className={'side-bar ' + className}>
    ...
  </nav>
))
```

I want to pass className

```
<SideBar className="app__sidebar"/>
```

I got this error:

```
(37,24): error TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type
   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<{ 
      current: Project | undefined; } &...'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is that you should use ownProps in mapStateToProps function and pass className prop to component obviously

```
function mapStateToProps(state: State, ownProps) {
  return {
    current: state.projects.current,
    className: ownProps.className
  }
}

const SideBar = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(({className, current}) => (
  <nav className={'side-bar ' + className}>
    ...
  </nav>
))
```

Comment: But what is I don't want to specify ownProps? I can do it in JS.